# PyQt4: QAbstractItemModel Object to QStandardItemModel Object

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, pyside, qabstractitemmodel, qstandarditemmodel

I have a QtGui.QAbstractItemModel object. I'd like to create a new QtGui.QStandardItemModel object based on the QtGui.QAbstractItemModel. Because QtGui.QStandardItemModel is sub-classed from  QtGui.QAbstractItemModel I should be able to copy all data from one object to another. How do you do so?

Usually you would something like this:

`data_model = QtGui.QAbstractItemModel()`

`new_data_model = QtGui.QAbstractItemModel(data_model)`

but the Constructor does not support instantiating with that type of argument.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`QAbstractItemModel` is an abstract class that can not and should not be instantiated. Its usefulness is mainly for inheritance since it serves as a basis for any type of model such as `QStandardItemModel`.

In addition to passing as a parent a model to another does not imply that the data will be copied, and finally `QAbstractItemModel` is in the submodule `QtCore`, not in `QtGui`.